# Pentaho ETL Transformation Using Lamda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

Is it possible to run Pentaho ETL Jobs/transformation using AWS Lamda functions?

I have Pentaho ETL jobs running on schedule on the Windows server, we are planning to migrate to AWS. I am considering the Lambda function. just to understand if it is possible to schedule the Pentaho ETL Jobs using AWS Lamdba

Comment: Pentaho seems to have [its own scheduler](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.4/0J0/0C0/040). Why would you want to use AWS Lambda to trigger jobs?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, the scheduler is an available option only with the enterprise edition not with the community version. Also to schedule jobs, I will need to set up server for Pentaho which I am trying to avoid and go serverless route and that's why AWS lambda function.

Comment: If you are asking whether it is possible to run Pentaho within an AWS Lambda function, then it's highly unlikely. Lambda functions can only run for a maximum of 15 minutes, have limited disk space and are designed for frequent short-running code (sometimes under 1 second!). I doubt that you could squeeze Pentaho into that environment.

Comment: I agree @JohnRotenstein. There are limitations to the Lambda function, and I spent the weekend trying to see if I can fit Pentaho code in AWS Lambda. I do have a working sample, I will shorty share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the snippet of code that I was able to successfully run in AWS Lambda Function.

handleRequest Function is called from AWS Lambda Function

```
    public Integer handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
        parseInput(input);
        return executeKtr(transName);

    }
```

parseInput: This function is used to parse out a string parameter passed by Lambda Function to extract KTR name and its parameters with value. Format of the input is "ktrfilename param1=value1 param2=value2"

```
    public static void parseInput(String input) {
        String[] tokens = input.split(" ");     
        transName = tokens[0].replace(".ktr", "") + ".ktr";
        for (int i=1; i<tokens.length; i++) {
            params.add(tokens[i]);
        }
    }
```

Executing KTR: I am using git repo to store all my KTR files and based on the name passed as a parameter KTR is executed

```
    public static Integer executeKtr(String ktrName) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Present Project Directory : " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));

            String transName = ktrName.replace(".ktr", "") + ".ktr";
            String gitURI = awsSSM.getParaValue("kattle-trans-git-url");
            String repoLocalPath = clonePDIrepo.cloneRepo(gitURI);

            String path = new File(repoLocalPath + "/" + transName).getAbsolutePath();
            File ktrFile = new File(path);

            System.out.println("KTR Path: " + path);
            try {
                /**
                 * IMPORTANT NOTE FOR LAMBDA FUNCTION MUST CREATE .KEETLE DIRECOTRY OTHERWISE
                 * CODE WILL FAIL IN LAMBDA FUNCTION WITH ERROR CANT CREATE
                 * .kettle/kettle.properties file.
                 * 
                 * ALSO SET ENVIRNOMENT VARIABLE ON LAMBDA FUNCTION TO POINT
                 * KETTLE_HOME=/tmp/.kettle
                 */
                Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("/tmp/.kettle"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Error Creating /tmp/.kettle directory");

            }

            if (ktrFile.exists()) {
                KettleEnvironment.init();
                TransMeta metaData = new TransMeta(path);
                Trans trans = new Trans(metaData);
//           SETTING PARAMETERS
                trans = parameterSetting(trans);

                trans.execute( null );
                trans.waitUntilFinished();
                if (trans.getErrors() > 0) {
                    System.out.print("Error Executing transformation");
                    throw new RuntimeException("There are errors in running transformations");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Successfully Executed Transformation");
                    return 1;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.print("KTR File:" + path + " not found in repo");
                throw new RuntimeException("KTR File:" + path + " not found in repo");
            }

        } catch (KettleException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

parameterSetting: If KTR is accepting parameter and it is passed while calling AWS Lambda function, it is set using parameterSetting function.

```
    public static Trans parameterSetting(Trans trans) {
        String[] transParams = trans.listParameters();

        for (String param : transParams) {
            for (String p: params) {
                String name = p.split("=")[0];
                String val = p.split("=")[1];
                
                if (name.trim().equals(param.trim())) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Setting Parameter:"+ name + "=" + val);
                        trans.setParameterValue(name, val);
                    } catch (UnknownParamException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        trans.activateParameters();
        return trans;
    }
```

CloneGitRepo:

```
public class clonePDIrepo {
    /**
     * Clones the given repo to local folder
     *
     * @param pathWithPwd Gir repo URL with access token included in the url. e.g.
     *                    https://token_name:token_value@github.com/ktr-git-repo.git
     * @return returns Local Repository String Path
     */
    public static String cloneRepo(String pathWithPwd) {
        try {
            /**
             * CREATING TEMP DIR TO AVOID FOLDER EXISTS ERROR, THIS TEMP DIRECTORY LATER CAN
             * BE USED TO GET ABSOLETE PATH FOR FILES IN DIRECTORY
             */
            File pdiLocalPath = Files.createTempDirectory("repodir").toFile();
            Git git = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(pathWithPwd).setDirectory(pdiLocalPath).call();
            System.out.println("Git repository cloned successfully");
            System.out.println("Local Repository Path:" + pdiLocalPath.getAbsolutePath());

            // }
            return pdiLocalPath.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

AWSSSMgetParaValue: Gets string value of the parameter passed.

```
    public static String getParaValue(String paraName) {

        try {
            Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
            SsmClient ssmClient = SsmClient.builder()
                    .region(region)
                    .build();

            
            GetParameterRequest parameterRequest = GetParameterRequest.builder()
                .name(paraName)
                .withDecryption(true)
                .build();
            GetParameterResponse parameterResponse = ssmClient.getParameter(parameterRequest);
            
            System.out.println(paraName+ " value retreived from AWS SSM");
            ssmClient.close();
            return parameterResponse.parameter().value();

        } catch (SsmException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
        }
   }
```

Assumptions:

1. Git repo is created with KTR files in the root of the repo
2. git repo url exists on the aws SSM with valid tokens to clone the repo
3. Input string contains name of the KTR file
4. Environment Variable is configured on Lambda Function for KETTLE_HOME=/tmp/.kettle
5. Lambda Function has necessary permissions for SSM and S3 VPC Network
6. Proper Security Group rules are setup to allow required network access for the KTR File

I am planning to upload complete code to git. I will update this post with the URL of the repository.

Comment: Worth to note: I used the maven project to build all dependency in a fat jar and the total size was around 112MB, AWS Lambda functions support a max of 250MB as of now.

Comment: Hi - I'm trying to stand up this same approach.  I've gotten the most basic transformation to run but running into issues loading classes for any more advanced transformation that uses steps with non-core plugins (e.g. JsonInputStep).  Did you ever upload to GitHub?  Any advice on issues with the plugins classes?

Comment: I haven't got a chance to uploade code to git. A lot of clean up to do with the code. I have added plugin classed to EFS and mounting EFS to the Lambda Function Directly. Changing class path during lambda launch sequence using AWS_LAMBDA_EXEC_WRAPPER.